# Cluster-robust errors for a plm with clustering at different level as fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, plm, standard-error

How does one get multiway clustered standard errors in R for plm objects, where the clustering is not at the level of the panel's time/group IDs?

The package `plm` provides support to calculate cluster-robust standard errors using the function `plm::vcovHC`. Unfortunately, this function only supports clustering at the group or time IDs of the panel. In certain cases one would want to cluster standard errors at a different level than the panel's unit of observation. An example is a regression with individual fixed effects where  variables at a higher level of aggregation are used as independent variables.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179631/individual-random-effects-model-with-standard-errors-clustered-on-a-different-va?rq=1) was asked in 2014 and a bootstrap function was recommended. This question differs because (1) I would like to cluster on two variables, not just one and (2) I would prefer not to use the bootstrap.

The package `multiwaycov` provides something very close to what I [want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027482/cluster-robust-standard-errors-in-stargazer), but unfortunately does not support plm objects.

Comment: Maybe `sandwich` or `multiwayvcov` packages.