# Cluster-Robust Standard Errors for Lmer and Glmer in Stargazer (lme4 package)

Tags: r, lme4, standard-error, random-effects

I have an experimental data set in which subjects were assigned to a specific treatment.
Each treatment consisted of 5 groups. I want to estimate a model that that includes random effects on subject level and then cluster the standard errors by the assigned group.

Does anyone know how to get stargazer to display clustered SEs on group level for i) lmer and ii) glmer models?

A similar question was asked some time ago for plm models

[individual random effects model with standard errors clustered on a different variable in R (R-project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179631/individual-random-effects-model-with-standard-errors-clustered-on-a-different-va?rq=1)

[Cluster-robust errors for a plm with clustering at different level as fixed effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242958/cluster-robust-errors-for-a-plm-with-clustering-at-different-level-as-fixed-effe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

There are two main problems.

First, I do not think that `stargazer` supports this. And if the feature is not currently supported, chances are good that it will not be supported in the near term. That package has not received a major update in several years.

Second, the two main packages to compute robust-cluster standard errors are `sandwich` and `clubSandwich`. `sandwich` does not support `lme4` models. `clubSandwich` supports `lmer` models but not `glmer`.

This means that you can get “half” of what you want by if you are willing to consider a more “modern” alternative to `stargazer`, such as [the `modelsummary` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

(Note that in the example below, I am using version 1.0.1 of the package. A small bug was introduced in 1.0.0 which slowed down mixed-effects models. It is fixed in the latest version.)

```r
install.packages("modelsummary", type = "source")
```

In this model, I print standard errors clustered by the `cyl` variable for the linear model:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(lme4)

mod1 <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + drat + (1 | cyl), data = mtcars)
mod2 <- glmer(am ~ hp + drat + (1 | cyl), data = mtcars, family = binomial)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

varcov1 <- vcovCR(mod1, cluster = mtcars$cyl, type = "CR0")
varcov2 <- vcov(mod2)

# converting the variance-covariance matrices to "standard" matrices
varcov1 <- as.matrix(varcov1)
varcov2 <- as.matrix(varcov2)

modelsummary(
    list(mod1, mod2),
    vcov = list(varcov1, varcov2))
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 12.790 | -29.076 |
|  | (5.104) | (12.418) |
| hp | -0.045 | 0.011 |
|  | (0.012) | (0.009) |
| drat | 3.851 | 7.310 |
|  | (1.305) | (3.047) |
| SD (Intercept cyl) | 1.756 | 0.000 |
| SD (Observations) | 3.016 | 1.000 |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| R2 Marg. | 0.616 | 0.801 |
| R2 Cond. | 0.713 |  |
| AIC | 175.5 | 28.1 |
| BIC | 182.8 | 34.0 |
| ICC | 0.3 |  |
| RMSE | 2.81 | 0.33 |

Comment: Hello Vincent, I implemented your solution for my dataset, however I get the following error when running vcovCR:   "Non-nested random effects detected. clubSandwich methods are not available for such models." The problem is that my random effects are for the individual subject while the clustering of SEs are on group level. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: No, sorry. Maybe you'll find something in the `clubSandwich` documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clubSandwich/clubSandwich.pdf

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm also having problems running ```clubSandwich``` with a model with two non-nested random effects. I've looked in the documentation but don't really see any solution. Has anyone ever resolved this error or been able to acquire robust SEs under these conditions?