Does glmer cluster the standard errors at the individual level?
I am a student in M1 in experimental economics. I am struggling with a glmer model because I don't know if the R function clusters the standard errors and if including a random intercept already had a similar effect (of clustering the standard errors). More precisely, I introduced a random intercept for controlling the intra-individual variability in my participants decisions (they take 18 decisions), but I am afraid to finish with biased results. In fact, I see that my residuals are not normally distributed (see below) and I am hoping it’s just because of this …
Btw, I've found this previous Overflow topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971844/cluster-robust-standard-errors-for-lmer-and-glmer-in-stargazer-lme4-package but it wasn't really informative (and it didn't work).
And this topic that let me think I must cluster my SE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179631/individual-random-effects-model-with-standard-errors-clustered-on-a-different-va
 but the function is different and I know it allows to cluster the SE quite easily.
enter image description here
The model:
summary(m1 <- glmer(sharing~iv_realf*condf+
          (1|ResponseID)+(1|replicates)+age+gender, 
        family=binomial, data=subset(d3, ac==2)))

Thus, I am wondering if I still have to cluster the SE (maybe the glmer function automatically does it) and if the random intercept accounts for the intra-variability from my participants answers.

glmer doesn't automatically compute cluster-robust SEs, and you might want to: look at Abadie, Alberto, Susan Athey, Guido W Imbens, and Jeffrey M Wooldridge. 2023. “When Should You Adjust Standard Errors for Clustering?” The Quarterly Journal of Economics 138 (1): 1–35. https://doi.org/10.1093/qje/qjac038.
This question gives examples using merDeriv and clubSandwich.  The latter package doesn't implement methods for GLMM, I'm not sure why (oversight?)
library(lme4)
library(merDeriv)
data(finance, package = "smdata")
m2 <- glmer(corr ~ jmeth + (1 | item), 
       data = finance,
       family = binomial, nAGQ = 20)
sandwich(m2, bread = bread(m2, full = TRUE),
         mean = meat(m2, level = 2))

However, this example doesn't work reasons I haven't been able to figure out yet:
library(mlmRev)
m <- glmer(use ~ livch + poly(age,2)*urban + (1|district),
           data = Contraception,
           family = binomial)
sand <- sandwich(m, bread = bread(m, full = TRUE),
         mean = meat(m, level = 2))


Super, thanks a lot ! I will investigate it

It seems that it's not an oversight. Here's the reasoning of the clubSandwich author for not covering GLMM: https://github.com/jepusto/clubSandwich/issues/97 . He says that "nobody has yet worked out small-sample corrected CRVE for GLMMs" and "it seems like one can certainly compute sandwich estimators for GLMMs, but what forms of model misspecification are they robust to?". Perhaps you would be able to give him some insights on the points he raises there.
